# How to make the HTML file

Tags: iphone

I am developing one application. In that app I am getting the html content from the `NSXMLParser`. And I need to send that html data to `UIWebView`. SO please tell me how to give that html data as input to `UIWebview` or how to create new html file with that data and how to run that html file?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow!
The Stack Overflow Community  might be able to help you figure out the problem
but is not able to without concrete data and this is not a "we write the code for you" type of site.
Help us help you, by sharing the code you're using right now, possibly some sample data and any possible errors you encounter.
Adapt your question to include those and you'll surely get a helpful answer. Thanks for considering. :)

Comment: Apple has taken time and effort to write the iOS documentation. It contains all the information you need, especially for something as basic as this. Have a look at `UIWebView`'s `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [UIWebView docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

This is the method you need to load your html:

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

Comment: I have only html data.DOn't have that baseurl.

Comment: @user1498119 You can pass nil to that paremeter.

Comment: NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><h1>Data</h1></body></html>" ];                                                 [web loadHTNLString:str baseURL:nil]; I write this one but it will show blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[mWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```